# Can I use fisher test on a $1 \times n$ table for comparing multiple proportions?

Tags: fishers-exact-test

Let $X$ be $1$ (success) if some event occurs and $0$ other wise, let $p_i$ be the proportion of successes in the population $i$, so I'd like to use fisher exact test to test:

$H_0: p_i=p_j$ for all $i \neq j$ with $i,j \in \{1,...,n\}$

$H_1:$ There is at least one difference.

Fisher exact test tests if there is an association between two categorical variables that is it tests if all counting elements of a 2x2 contigency table are the same, in upper side of the table we have the first categoric variable and its levels and in left side we have the other. On my way I modified the table to be $1 \times n$ (row $\times$ column) sized where the upper side would be the population index and each element in the table would be the counting of successes in each sample (with known number of failures) from each population. Finally I'd like to know if I'm able to use Fisher exact test in this situation to test if the proportion of successes are the same or am I just able to use fisher test with two categoric variables on a 2x2 contigency table?

Comment: I don’t see why you have one column instead of two. Could you please explain that?

Comment: one row, this one row has $n$ countings of success for each sample from the respective population.

Comment: Do you know how many failures (or total attempts) there were?

Comment: yes as I know the sample size

Comment: So why don’t you have a column with the number of successes and another with the number of failures?

Comment: for it looks like a contingency table regarding the traditional use of fisher test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several procedures in R give much the same result.

Suppose Yes's and No's in four categories are as follows.

```
Yes = c(51,74, 22, 2)
No =  c(57, 99, 55, 5)
All = Yes + No
TBL = rbind(Yes, No)
TBL
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
Yes   51   74   22    2
No    57   99   55    5
```

Test to see if proportions of Yes's are the same in all four categories:

```
prop.test(Yes, All, cor=F)

        4-sample test for equality of proportions 
        without continuity correction

data:  Yes out of All
X-squared = 7.3227, df = 3, p-value = 0.06229
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2    prop 3    prop 4 
0.4722222 0.4277457 0.2857143 0.2857143 

Warning message:
In prop.test(Yes, All, cor = F) :
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

The warning message is given because of the small counts in Category 4.
(Essentially, this test uses a normal approximation, expressed in terms of
a chi-squared statistic with 3 DF.)

The `prop.test` procedure in R is essentially the same as a chi-squared test of
homogeneity on `TBL`, without the Yates continuity correction.

```
chisq.test(TBL, cor=F)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 7.3227, df = 3, p-value = 0.06229

Warning message:
In chisq.test(TBL) : 
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

In this version of the test, it is easier to show explicitly why the
P-value may be incorrect. The warning message is given whenever
any one of the expected counts in the chi-squared test is smaller than
$5.$ Here is how to display the table of expected counts. Notice that
the P-value is exactly the same as above.

```
chisq.test(TBL, cor=F)$exp
        [,1]      [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
Yes 44.08767  70.62192 31.43288 2.857534
No  63.91233 102.37808 45.56712 4.142466

Warning message:
In chisq.test(TBL, cor=F) : 
 Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

However, as implemented in R, it is possible to simulate a more
accurate P-value (using the parameter `sim=T`). Notice the (slight)
change in the simulated P-value.

```
chisq.test(TBL, sim=T)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test 
        with simulated p-value 
        (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  TBL
X-squared = 7.3227, df = NA, p-value = 0.06347
```

Traditionally, Fisher's exact test (based on a hypergeometric distribution according to marginal counts) was limited to $2 \times 2$
tables with relatively small counts. However, its implementation
in R can use larger tables (within limits of available computer
memory to do the computations). The table `TBL` is as suggested in one of @Dave's Comments.

```
fisher.test(TBL)

        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  TBL
p-value = 0.05681
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

*Note:* For the fictitious data used here, all tests are significant at
the 7% level, but not at the 5% level. Often simulated P-value
of the chi-squared test of homogeneity and the P-value of
Fisher's exact test are more different from one another than
for these data.

Comment: This example states a  $2 \times 4$ table not a $1 \times n$ if I have only "Yes" and the other four ($n$) levels of any category , Could I still use this, if so, I'll consider your answer.

Comment: Sorry you are right, I know the failures, good answer